# How to remove all special char except $ (dollar sign) using php?

Tags: php, preg-replace

How to remove all special char except `$` (dollar sign) using php ?

I tried use this

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $string);
```

But all special char include `$` (dollar sign) was remove

i tried this too  `$string = preg_replace("/$[^ \w]+/", "", $string);`

But not work.

I want to store `$` (dollar sign) , How can i do that ?

Comment: Please elaborate on "special char".

Comment: 1. You use `PHP` 2. You have a `regex` 3. And you have a problem with the `dollar sign` => https://google.com Search: `PHP regex dollar sign` and you will find out, that the dollar sign has a special meaning

Comment: thank VolkerK : special char is all char except `space`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `$`

Comment: \w accepts an underscore, which is not in the list robert gave us.

Answer (score 2):

You're accepting so few characters that you could just "spell them out": everything that is not A-Z0-9$ -> replace.

```
<?php
$input= '_~!@#$%^&*()+  babnQWWWEWQEJ';
echo preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9$]+/', '', $input);
```